# Query regarding motion of a cylinder

Tags: homework-and-exercises, newtonian-mechanics, forces, rotational-dynamics

I need help understanding the motion of this cylinder...
Cylinder A of mass M is resting on two smooth edges, one fixed and other is that of a block B. At an instant block B is pulled toward left with a constant speed v. The distance between the two edges was zero.
Why does the cylinder move horizontally?
[image]

Comment: Is there a no-slip condition on the corner?

Comment: This is a kinematically unstable situation, where the cylinder might roll about the table corner at one instant, and roll about the block corner the next instant. Even if all information was provided the cylinder would chaotically switch between the two motion scenarios at an indeterminate time.

Comment: @JAlex yes, there is a no-slip condition on the corner...

Comment: Which corner of the two?